# I am not getting proper response. I am getting [object Object]

Tags: angular

I am calling `onSubmit()` function from *contact-form.component.ts* file and function is created *cmspage.service.ts* function is `contactForm(formdata: Contact)`

I am getting following output in console

> Backend returned code 200, body was: [object Object]

```
<section class="cmspage mtb-40">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-desc" [hidden]="submitted">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h1>Contact</h1>
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #contactForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required #name="ngModel">
              <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                  Name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" required email #email="ngModel">
              <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" [(ngModel)]="model.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" [(ngModel)]="model.message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required #message="ngModel"></textarea>
              <div *ngIf="message.invalid && (message.dirty || message.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="message.errors.required">Message is required.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button [disabled]="!contactForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-error" *ngIf="error">
      <h1>{{error.errorTitle}}</h1>
      <h3>{{error.errorDesc}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!submitted" class="contact-message">
      <div *ngIf="model.id" class="contact-success">
        <h2 class="success">Success!</h2>
        <h4>Contact form has been successfully submitted.</h4>
        <br />
        <button (click)="gotoHome()" class="btn btn-info">Go to Home</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*contact-form.component.ts*

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.model);
    this.submitted=true;
    return this.cmspageService.contactForm(this.model).subscribe(
      data=>this.model=data,
      error => this.error=error
    );
  }
```

*cmspage.service.ts*

```
export class CmspageService {
  ServerUtl = "http://localhost/dev/blogger/";
  errorData : {};
  httpOptions = {
    headers:new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  };
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  contactForm(formdata: Contact){
    console.log(formdata);
    return this.http.post<Contact>(this.ServerUtl+'api/contact',formdata,this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {

      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.

      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {

      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.

      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.

      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    // return an observable with a user-facing error message

    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be possible, there is no error to catch if the backend returns code 200. You should log `console.error(error.error)` directly to see what the api has returned, that will give you a clue.

Comment: error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Doesn't look like the backend is sending you JSON, inspect the network request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the backend response is indeed json content and contains the header 'Content-Type' with the value 'application/json'

You can see this in the browser developer tools, under the 'Network' tab.

Edit: With the additional information you added, it appears the backend is not sending json. I'd suggest to fix the backend service, that you appear to have control over since it is a local endpoint.

Comment: yes it is showing : Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 but still ouput is error [object][object[

Comment: Is this indeed for the server response with return code 200? Can you add `console.dir(error.error)` in the handleError method and tell the output of it?

Comment: I have added console.dir(error.error)

SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7932:51)

and yes Status Code: 200 OK

Comment: Then the backend is not sending json, so the client cannot properly deserialize the response. You should fix the backend service. What is this response string starting with 'A' ? You can see the whole body, under "Response" after clicking that specific http request